# The negative assertions in PHP regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I try to find all the usernames in the form of `http://www.test.com/username/`, but not in the form of `http://www.test.com/username/ANY_VALID_URL_PART`. I [tried the negative assertions in PHP](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/6lh), but failed.

Let the content be:

```
<a href="http://www.test.com/username1/show" http://www.test.com/username2/ http://www.test.com/username3 target="_blank">
```

I want to get the username part in `http://www.test.com/username/` and `http://www.test.com/username` But I also want to ignore the username in `http://www.test.com/username/show`. I tried the following:

```
preg_match_all("/(https?:\/\/www.test.com)\/([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]+)(?<!(\/[A-Za-z0-9&?_-]))/i", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

But the result is:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => http://www.test.com/username1
        [1] => http://www.test.com/username2
        [2] => http://www.test.com/username3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => http://www.test.com
        [1] => http://www.test.com
        [2] => http://www.test.com
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => username1
        [1] => username2
        [2] => username3
    )

)
```

Could anyone tell me why the `(?<!(\/[A-Za-z0-9&?_-]))` is not working, and how to fix it?

Even thought I can only choose one answer, I really appreciate all for your help!!!

Comment: It isn't entirely clear that this is what you want, but why not just `/$` at the end to prevent matching longer strings?

Comment: Hello @Brad ! Actually I do not want the username1 here. Is there any way to exclude it? Besides, if I add `$` at the end, the result becomes empty.

Comment: I think you're looking for `(?:`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of **Negative Lookbehind** you should be using [**Negative Lookahead**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookarounds).

```
preg_match_all('~https?://www\.test\.com/([a-z0-9]+\b)(?!/[\w?&=-])~i', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

**Note:** You need to escape the dots `.` in your regular expression as well. And if you only want to grab the username portion of the url you can use one capturing group, you don't need three here.

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xE1gD0/3)

Comment: Yes, I forgot to escape the dots

Comment: Sorry, I was puzzle about your `\b` mark. And your RE exclude the `http://www.test.com/username6/>` http://regex101.com/r/xE1gD0/1 Could you please give me more help and instructions? Thanks!

Comment: With your RE, I get it working: http://regex101.com/r/xE1gD0/2  But could you please give me short explaination or reference about the `-b`. Thanks!

Comment: Yes `\b` is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). A word boundary does not consume any characters. It asserts that on one side there is a word character, and on the other side there is not.

Comment: I am looking for the username part in `http://www.test.com/username/`, which does NOT have any tailing URL part. (Like `http://www.test.com/username/Hello`) Your code works now! THX!